# Why can't I subscript Array with a Int32 index?

Tags: arrays, swift, subscript

Could you tell me why it's not possible to use a `Int32` (or `UInt`, `UInt8`, etc.) index to subscript `Array`? The following code show examples of what work and what doesn't work:

```
var buffer = [UInt8]()
buffer.append(0)

buffer[0] = 1    // Valid
buffer[-1] = 1   // Valid :)

var index1:Int = 0
buffer[index1] = 1 // Valid

var index2:Int32 = 0
buffer[index2] = 1 // Invalid
```

The last line results in this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt8]' with an index of type 'Int32'

Comment: Please edit your question and refrain from using outbursts like “Ridiculous” and writing word in bold capitalized letters.

Comment: Because the *index* type of `Array`as the associated type `Index` of the `(Mutable)Collection` protocol which `Array` conforms to is defined as `Int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift, `Array` conforms to—among other things—`MutableCollection` which defines an associated `Index` type, which is used for subscripting. This can be seen in the following `MutableCollection.subscript` signature:

```
subscript(position: Index) -> Element { get set }
```

In the `Array` implementation of `MutableCollection` the `Index` type is defined as `Int`. This is why `Array` expects `Int` values for its indexed subscript.

---

In the examples in your question, the reason why `buffer[0] = 1` works is because both `Int` (the index type) and `UInt8` (the element type) conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. When the type system infers the types of the index (and the element) it sees that the value being passed requires the type to conform to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` and that `Array.Index` requires the type to be `Int`. Since both of these are satisfiable (because `Int` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`), the type system infers that the `0` is an `Int`. The same process applies to inferring that the `1` is a `UInt8`.

In the later two examples the `index1` and `index2` variables have been explicitly typed as `Int` and `Int32` respectively. When passing `index1` to `Array.subscript` which expects an `Int` index, the types match. However, when passing `index2` (which is of type `Int32` to `Array.subscript` which expects an `Int` index, there is a type mismatch. `Array` expects an `Int` index and the `index2` variable is explicitly typed as `Int32` which is a different type. There is no inference of the index type because these values aren't passed as literals, but rather as variables with a specific type.

Comment: "On 32-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int32, and on 64-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int64." see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int. If `Index` expects `Int` it would work on a 32-Bit system.

Comment: Yes, depending on the platform `Int` may have the same size as either `Int32` or `Int64` but having the same size doesn't make it the same type.

Comment: I think you are right since `Int32` and `Int64` are both not working as `Index`. `Int` is then no `typealias` to either of them.